# mahout - create item based recommender with Preferences

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

How can I create in mahout an item based recommender that is calculating his distance by the preferences values, and the logLiklihood algorithm together?
can I merge to distance measures together?

The GenericItemBasedRecommender is getting a similarity - `new GenericItemBasedRecommender(model, similarity)`

what will be similarity if I want to calculate that from logLikelihood + some calculation based on the features?

Do I need to implement a new `itemSimilarity`?

Comment: Apples and oranges, LLR is a probability measure, distance is not. By your mention of features it sounds like you are trying to mix collaborative filtering and metadata similarity. Can you describe why you want this, there may be some way other than combining incompatible measures.

Comment: @pferrel I have one boolean feature 1/0, while I want to give more boost to the 1 values. I think it is quite reasonable, and still in the scope of collaborative filtering.